# Append enclosure in a for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop

I cannot understand why the append enclosure in square brackets do not work with an incremental point, but it works without the incremental point. It maybe, it gets out of bound ?

Here, in square brackets, it exists the incremental point "[m+1]" but it is not working properly the "for loop" in python. 
    lst=[]
    for m in xrange(0,5,1):
        rs=[0,0,0,3]
        rg=range(5)
        lst.append(rg[m+1] if rs==0 or rg[m+1]>3 else 0)

While, here, in square brackets, it does not exist the incremental point "[m]" but it is working properly the "for loop" in python.

```
lst=[]
for m in xrange(0,5,1):
    rs=[0,0,0,3]
    rg=range(5)
    lst.append(rg[m+1] if rs==0 or rg[m]<3 else 0)
```

...and another example, by changing the direction of the sign "<" to ">". It is not working properly.

```
lst=[]
for m in xrange(0,5,1):
    rs=[0,0,0,3]
    rg=range(5)
    lst.append(rg[m+1] if rs==0 or rg[m]>3 else 0)
```

Comment: Please tag this question with the programming language you are using.

Comment: If this is python, it evaluates fine for me.

Comment: i changed my question, a typo maybe was in process. I was editing the question when you answered it!

Comment: This is a very different question to what you originally posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m` will go from 0 to 4.

`rg` has 5 elements with indexes 0 to 4.

When `m` is 4 you try to append `rg[m+1]` to `lst` (depending on the condition), which would try to access `rg[5]` which is out of range, since there is no such index in `rg`.

Comment: You are right @Wodin, i found that, the left part of an if inline statement, -at leats- is not validated until the right part is validated... check my own answer too... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer!

an inline statement validate first the right part and then the left part. 
Left part of an inline statement can be erroneous stated until left part be validated. Therefore, you may have an if inline statement, that most of times, the right part is TRUE but the left part can remain faulty!

How can you check this? you must insert additional logical checks in that case? this is the only solution?

for example, this will always validate the right part, which will result 0, BUT never it will validate the left part.

```
r=[0,1]
a=[2,3]

r[99999] if a[1]==2 else 0
```

Comment: Finally, my answer was that statement `((0 if m<20 else m+1) if rs==0 else 0)`. i wanted to leave all items less than 20, and in the same time to increase all individual items by 1. This was done by that if / inline statement. thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

`for m in xrange(0,5,1)` = `for m in iter([0,1,2,3,4])`

`rg=range(5)` = `rg=[0,1,2,3,4]`

The condition `rg[m]>3` is `True` if `m = 4`. So you have `lst.append(rg[4+1])`. `rg[5]` is out of range of `rg`

P/S: How can you check `rs == 0` while `rs=[0,0,0,3]`? It returns always `False`